# Show that there is a series in R^infinity has some term greater than or equal to 1/n but that also is arbitrary close to the zero sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider $\mathbb{R}^\infty = \{(a_n): \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n^2 < \infty\}$ with the metric $d((a_n$), ($b_n$)) = $[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n - b_n)^2]^{1/2}$. Let $A = \{(a_n) : |a_n| < 1/n \text{ for all } n\}$.

Show that for every $\epsilon > 0$, $B(\textbf{0}, \epsilon) \bigcap A^C \ne \emptyset$ where $\textbf{0}$ represents the 0 sequence.

Here's what I'm thinking:

I'm trying to find a sequence $(a_n)$ where some term is greater than $1/n$ but also where $d((a_n), \textbf{0}) < \epsilon$. However, this would mean that

$[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n - b_n)^2]^{1/2} = [\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2]^{1/2} < \epsilon$, or $[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2] < \epsilon^2$.

So, wouldn't this mean that $(a_n)$ must be the zero sequence if this holds true for all epsilon? I know this cannot be correct because then $B(\textbf{0}, \epsilon) \subset A$, which is the opposite of what we're trying to prove.

Comment: You've got your quantifiers mixed up: You don't need an $\left(a_n\right)$ that works for all $\epsilon$, rather you need to show that for any given $\epsilon$, you can constuct an $\left(a_n\right)$ that works for that particular $\epsilon$.

Comment: @MartianInvader Okay, so how would I go about finding such a sequence? I tried constructing something like a geometric series that converges to $\epsilon^2$, but I couldn't get it to work so that the terms were greater than 1/n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first i will give you a hint, but after you can continue reading and see the answer.

you need to find a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2]^{1/2} < \epsilon$

and theres an $k\in \mathbb N$ such that $a_k\ge \frac 1 k$. try to think on the most trivial sequence that comes in mind.

**now the answer**

lets take $\epsilon>0$ there is $k\in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac \epsilon 2 \ge \frac 1 k$

lets define the sequence $(a_n)$: for $n=k$ we say that $a_n= \frac \epsilon 2 $ else $a_n=0$.

so $(a_n)$ gets zero in every coordination except on the $k$ coordination, wich there it gets the value $\frac \epsilon 2 $.

so indeed we get that $[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2]^{1/2}=\frac \epsilon 2<\epsilon$ so it is in the ball

and $a_k\ge \frac 1 k$ so $(a_n)$ is not in $A$ as requested

Comment: Oh, yeah, that makes sense! I was thinking all the terms of the sequence had to be nonzero, but that makes sense to just change one term. Thank you!

Comment: glad i could help! an up vote will be well received;)